# PHP APC configuration, and checking performance

Tags: php, caching, apc

I am having a little issue on checking APC in my VPS host, which is a CentOs 6.5 on a 32bit system, running php-fpm, Nginx and Mysql. To optimize memory, I installed php-apc and configured it according to [to this tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-apc-configuration-and-usage-tips-and-tricks/)

Basically, I only changed the things that made the least sense (As this was my first time using caching, and optimization ever, so I left the rest)

So, these are the configurations I changed in `/etc/php.d/apc.ini.`

```
extension = apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=128M
apc.ttl=3600
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.max_file_size=1M
apc.stat=1
```

Now, after starting php, I wanted to know if all is working, and that caching is activated and working, but I am not sure how this is done.

I checked the `phpinfo()`'s output, and I can see that apc is loaded but other than that, I don't know how to check if it is working at all. According to the php manual 
I am able to understand `apc.enabled = 1` means, apc is working ??

Is there a command or some output to even debug or check on performance of apc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[apc_cache_info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cache-info.php) will give you output detailing how the cache is currently configured, hit/miss statistics, and also list the contents of the cache.

There is also a useful information page provided with the APC PECL package. You can find this on your system by issuing

```
locate apc.php
```

in your unix shell (eg bash). 
You may need to copy the resulting file to a location in your webserver's root, so you can get to it with a browser.